# AngularJS success function of promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I have made a HTTP post API call to a URL.

I am getting the response, but I am confused how to write a success function, as there are many ways for it.

Here's my API call. Please help me how would the success function would be like?

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: viewProfileurl,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.token,
    },
    params: {
        'action':'view'
    }
}

$http(req);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular uses promise internally in `$http` implementation i.e. [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

> A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their
>   return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.

So, there are two options:

### 1st option

You can use the `.success` and `.error` callbacks:

```
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: viewProfileurl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.token,
  },
  params: {
    'action': 'view'
  }

}

$http(req).success(function() {
    // do on response success
}).error(function() {
});
```

But this `.success` & `.error` are deprecated.

- [Official deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)
- http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/

So, go for the 2nd option.

### 2nd Option

Use `.then` function instead

```
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: viewProfileurl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.token,
  },
  params: {
    'action': 'view'
  }

}

$http(req).then(function() {
    // do on response success
}, function() {
   // do on response failure
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a success callback to retrive the data returned by your API.

```
$http(req)
     .then(function (response) {
         var data = resposne.data;
         ...
      }, function (error) {
         var errorStatusCode = error.StatusCode;
         var errorStatus = error.Status;
         ...
      });
```

Basically $http returns a promise and you need to write a callback function.

Or you can do something like this:

```
$http(req).success(function(respData) { var data = respData; ... });
$http(req).error(function(err) { ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is **success and error** syntax

```
    $http.get("/api/my/name")
  .success(function(name) {
    console.log("Your name is: " + name);
  })
  .error(function(response, status) {
    console.log("The request failed with response " + response + " and status code " + status);
  };
```

Using **then**

```
$http.get("/api/my/name")
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log("Your name is: " + response.data);
  }, function(result) {
    console.log("The request failed: " + result);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

`$http` returns a promise that has a `then` function that you can use.

```
$http(req).then(function (data) { ...; });
```

The definition of `then`:

```
then(successCallback, failCallback)
```